# Optional or Conditional model associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, belongs-to, has-one

I have a user model.
Users can have 1 of 3 roles: role1, role2, role3. This is represented by a 'role' column in the user model.
Each role has a unique profile. role1_profile, role2_profile, role3_profile. Each *_profile is a model.

How do I represent this optional association in Rails?

I've tried it two different ways:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    #FIRST WAY
    if current_user.role == 'role1' then has_one :role1_profile end 
    #SECOND WAY
    has_one :role1_profile, :conditions => ['user.role = ?', 'role1']
end
```

But that doesn't work. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Associations are not intended to be conditional.  It's probably easiest to keep things that way, too.

How about having a polymorphic association between `User` and the various role profiles?

```
class User
  belongs_to :role_profile, :polymorphic => true
end

class RoleXProfile
  has_many :users, :as => :role_profile
end
```

Of course, you would need to add the `role_profile_id` and `role_profile_type` fields to your users table.

No matter what you do you will need to check the user's role or role_profile wherever you use it.

Comment: Thank you! I think your solution is perfect. There's always a way in Rails, but when you don't know the way, you tend to implement a solution in a weird way.

Comment: @jackquack I don't think your approach was weird at all.  Quite the opposite, it was very logical.  And it may very well point out a place where ActiveRecord can be improved/extended.  Anyway, I'm glad you got things working.

Answer (score 4):

You  might want to consider a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) instead and just have appropriate role profiles.

My understanding was that the `:conditions` were conditions the *associated* model must meet (but I could be wrong on that).

In any case, I think you're making this more difficult than it really is and obfuscating what you really need by making these relationships conditional.

Comment: +1 because a lazy programmer is a good programmer :) and for the note about conditions used for associations

Comment: @WizardofOgz That's what I keep telling my boss! I think it was... Hamlet? who said "Out of laziness comes innovation."

Comment: You're absolutely right! I just gave Wizard the cred since he included code. :)